# Javascript nested FOR loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, nested

I'm doing some js exercises and want to print something like this
(without the dots):

```
*****
****5
***45
**345
*2345
```

with nested FOR loops (or FORs combined with IFs)

My try:

```js
var n = 5;
var stars = "";

for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
        stars = "";
    for(var j=i; j<n; j++){
        stars = stars + " *";
    }
    for(var k=i; k>0; k--){
        stars = stars + " " + k;
    }
    console.log(stars);
}
```

I just can't make the numbers as in the example above despite of positions being correct. 
Any ideas?

Comment: j=n-i in the second for loop

Comment: And i=1 as you wanna start with 1 number

Answer (score 1):

That's because you append text to `stars` variable instead of `lineOfStars`. ;-)

Comment: yes, but I edited it after pasting and just forgot about it - so that's not the issue but thanks:)
pozdro:)

Answer (score 1):

This is a matrix. You can draw it with **one nested loop**, **not with two**, Just use the `j < n - i + 1` condition with **2 loops**.

```js
var n = 5;
var lineOfStars = '';

for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++){
  
  for(var j = 1; j <= n; j++){
    
     if(j <= n - i + 1){
       
       lineOfStars += '*' ;
       
     } else{
       
        lineOfStars += j ;
       
     }
  }
  
  lineOfStars += '\n' ;
  
}

console.log(lineOfStars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer I could think of.

```js
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
 let str = "";
 
 for(let j = 0; j < (5 - i); j++){
  str += "*";
 }
 
 while(str.length < 5){
  str += str.length + 1;
 }

 console.log(str);
 
}
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - you can also add code as well as the comments in the code itself 
- in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question. 
This is especially important for an older question and the questions that already have answers.

Answer (score -1):

Your unexpected behaviour is happening because you log out on each iteration of `i` but don't reset your `lineOfStars` variable.

- As you want to start with the 5 and then 4, etc, it may be conceptually easier to iterate downwards in the outer loop rather than upwards.
- As you want the first line to start with all `*`s, you need to begin the outer iteration from `n + 1`
- As you don't want to include the line beginning `1`, you need to end the outer iteration after `2` (before `1`)
- As you don't want to count `0`, you need to begin your inner iterations from `1`

Another way to do it would be to log out only once on completion

e.g. in ES6

```js
function countingStars(n) {
    const star = '*';
    let str = '';
    
    for (let i = n + 1; i > 1; --i) {
        for (let j = 1; j < i; ++j) {
            str += ' ' + star;
        }
        for (let j = i; j <= n; ++j) {
            str += ' ' + j.toString();
        }
        str += '\n';
    }
    
    return str;
}

const stars = countingStars(5);
console.log(stars);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var n = 5;
var stars = "";

var k = n;
for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
  for (var j=0; j<n; j++) {
    if (j < k ) {
      stars += " *";
    } else {
      stars += " " + (j + 1);
    }
  }
  k--;
  stars += "\n";
}
console.log(stars);
```